# Spring Build ContextLoads FAILED

Tags: spring

I have a big problem. When I'm building my Project, I get this Error:

```
com.eurofunk.RaceComApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Are you running Spark by any chance? I'm also experiencing the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown

> if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

So this does not look like a spring related problem.
It looks more like a problem with the JRE or a bean tries to find a native library which does not exist.